# Python 2.7 Using a FOR Loop

Tags: for-loop

Hey guys basically Im trying to use a FOR loop to ask the username of the actor and actress to search for and printing out if that certain actor is in the movie as well as printing if they are not in the movie. Im very stuck so far and do not know how to ask my code for my actors

```
print ("Which actor/actress you want to look for?")
actors []
for actor in actors:
  If actor == actors:
    print ("Yes, %s is in the show breaking bad") (actors,)
    break
  else:
    print ( "NO , %s is not in the show breaking bad") (actors,)
    print actor
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the basic idea, but your code is all over the place.

Try something like:

```
search_name = raw_input('Please enter the actor to search for: ')
actors = ['Idris Elba', 'Dwayne Johnson', 'Mel Brooks']

if search_name in actors:
  print search_name + 'is in the movie!'
else:
  print search_name + 'is NOT in the movie!'
```

If you want to continue asking until the input is a name in the list, use a loop:

```
search_name = raw_input('Please enter the actor to search for: ')
actors = ['Idris Elba', 'Dwayne Johnson', 'Mel Brooks']

while search_name not in actors:
  print search_name + 'is NOT in the movie!'
  search_name = raw_input('Please enter a different actor's name:')

print search_name + 'is in the movie!'
```